# track changes to users/groups

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft.Graph.Core
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Core/1.14.1
to track changes to Users and Groups.

I call delta queries for this objects and it works well

```
var request = _serviceClient.Groups.Delta().Request();
```

But how can I get changes when Group's membership collection is changed? 
For example, user added to group.
I have no changes to group and no changes to user.

Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the Group's `members` collection. This will tell Graph to surface any membership changes as part of the delta. The URI looks like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$expand=members
```

To execute this using the [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet), you would call it like this:

```
var groupDelta = await graphClient
    .Groups
    .Delta()
    .Request()
    .Expand("members")
    .GetAsync();
```